# A query only works with small data and with more data it just won't work

Tags: json, bigdata

I have exported data from firestore to bigquery. This data is exported in a JSON format. I can get data with a limit of 50 but when i put a limit of 100 there's this error:

`Failed to coerce output value false to type ARRAY<STRING>.`

I don't know exactly what this error means, but i have googled the problem only none of those explanations are suited for my problem. There were two problems, only one i have already figured out. This is why the code may look unnecessary.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    return jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
""" OPTIONS ( library="gs://suncamp-1106/jsonpath-0.8.0.js.txt" );

SELECT
  A
, B
, C
, SPLIT(ARRAY_TO_STRING(D, ','), ',') as D
FROM (
SELECT   
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.A') as A
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.B') as B
, IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(data), r'subarray.*c'), CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(lower(data), "$.array['subarray']"), '$[*].c'), null) AS C
, IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(data), r'subarray.*d'), CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(lower(data), "$.array['subarray']"), '$[*].d'), null) AS D
FROM
  `mydataset`)
```

The data looks something like this:

A is a name
B is a birthdate
C is a datetime that depends on the next record, It puts a collects the date for the search term
D is a search term

I expect that I can get results from my query whether I put a limit or not.